# Alternative to Vlookup function

Tags: excel

I have a sheet containing calender and a log sheet. This log sheet displays orders with detailed info. The log sheet has more than 1 entries of same date & the Calender uses Vlookup function so it displays only one order on that date. Can anyone assist me in finding an function so it can read all the orders with same date and display in the calender??

Comment: `FILTER()`, `TEXTJOIN()` will work in this case.

Comment: Without a data sample and expected output this is a shot in the darkness, but maybe with Pivot Tables or SUMPRODUCT

Comment: Both are correct ^^^ --> `FILTER()` or `TEXTJOIN()` should work, again without sample data its unlikely to say which formula suits with your database.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I will try them. I have tried to add the images of both the sheets. Please view them and provide any suggestions. Thank you